# How many admob AdUnitID from different user/publisher can be used in the same app?

Tags: admob, mobile-development, admob-rewardedvideoad, revenue-sharing

For instance, suppose I have a social media application with over 10M users. In that case, I will gather the AdUnitID of the creators to display advertisements based on their AdUnitID to their followers, encouraging them to create more content.

Sharing Your knowledge about this will be more helpful.
Thanks